# How to navigate back to last route with react-router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, react-router, meteor-accounts

I'm building a [Meteor + React + Material-UI](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/tree/devel/examples/material-ui-leaderboard) app and I'm using [react-router](http://alexgaribay.com/2015/09/22/meteor-react-and-react-router-revisited/) and [meteor-accounts-react-material-ui](https://github.com/qnub/meteor-accounts-react-material-ui).

The docs for [meteor-accounts-react-material-ui](https://github.com/qnub/meteor-accounts-react-material-ui) show examples using FlowRouter to specify a `redirect` function to call after successful login:
`<Accounts.ui.LoginFormSet redirect={handleLogin}/>`

Since I don't believe you can pass the `redirect` property to the `Accounts.ui.LoginFormSet` component with react-router's route:

```
Routes = React.createClass({  
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {};
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route name="home" path="/login" component={LoginWrapper}/>
      </Router>
    );
  }
});
```

The best way I can figure out how to reproduce this with react-router is to wrap the `Accounts.ui.LoginFormSet` component like so:

```
var LoginWrapper = React.createClass({
  handleLogin: function() {
    //what do I put in here?
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
        <Accounts.ui.LoginFormSet redirect={this.handleLogin}/>    
    );
  }
});
```

However, what I can't seem to figure out is how to actually redirect to the last route that called the `/login` route (i.e. the referrer).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this answer from [qnub on Github](https://github.com/qnub/meteor-accounts-react-material-ui/issues/1#issuecomment-157647982), I managed to resolve this issue:

```
var LoginWrapper = React.createClass({
  handleLogin: function() {
      // redirect through ReactRouter if it have ability or through window:
      window.location.href = this.targetUrl;
  },
  render: function () {
    this.targetUrl = window.location.href; // save target URL from window on through ReactRouter if it have ability
    return (
        <Accounts.ui.LoginFormSet redirect={this.handleLogin}/>    
    );
  }
});
```